# python list operations to modify the list shape

Tags: python, numpy

np in this context is numpy.

z_mesh is array of shape 41*401.

I need dz_theta_mat and dz_gamma_mat of shape 20*200 by subtracting [2*i,2*j]th element from [2*i,2*j+2]th element and [2*i,2*j]th element from [2*i+2,2*j]th element respectively.

My attempt doesn't give the required shape for the list.

how do i modify it to obtain the required result?

```
print np.shape(z_mesh)
dz_gamma_mat = [z_mesh[2*i,2*j+2]-z_mesh[2*i,2*j] for i,j in itertools.product(range(20),range(199))]
print np.shape(fish_dz_gamma_mat)
dz_theta_mat = [z_mesh[2*i+2,2*j]-z_mesh[2*i,2*j] for i, j in itertools.product(range(19),range(200))]
print np.shape(fish_dz_theta_mat)

(41, 401)
(3980,)
(3800,)
```

Comment: Lists don't have shapes.  Do you mean array when you say list?

Comment: yes it is an array sorry for my terminology.I am new to python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1714410) and subtract?

```
dz_theta_mat = z_mesh[:-1:2, 2::2] - z_mesh[:-1:2, :-1:2]
dz_gamma_mat = z_mesh[2::2, :-1:2] - z_mesh[:-1:2, :-1:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast your result as `numpy` array and then reshape your result, e.g.:

```
dz_theta_mat = np.array([z_mesh[2*i+2,2*j]-z_mesh[2*i,2*j] for i, j in itertools.product(range(19),range(200))]).reshape(z_mesh.shape)
```